# Math Equation needs to be linked with lines

Tags: beamer, math-mode

[image]

Can anyone please help in writing the following expression in Latex Beamer

Comment: Could you please at least provide the formulae, i.e. type them? And while you are waiting for an answer, please revisit the previous questions of yours and check if it is worthwhile to accept the answers.

Comment: I am sorry but people haven't given me answers to my prior questions that I can accept as correct answers.

Comment: Here I just need the code for the following design in Latex beamer, all the rest we can fix. Right??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[3][]{\tikz[remember
picture,baseline=(#2.base)]{\node(#2)[inner sep=0pt,#1]{$\displaystyle #3$};}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{8cm}
\begin{align*}
 P\,\sin\frac{\pi}{15}
 =&\frac{1}{2}\tikznode{1}{\left(\sin\frac{\pi}{15}\,\cos\frac{\pi}{15}\right)}
 \,\tikznode{2}{\cos\frac{2\pi}{15}}\,\cos\frac{3\pi}{15}
 \,\tikznode{3}{\cos\frac{4\pi}{15}}\,\cos\frac{6\pi}{15}
 \,\tikznode{4}{\cos\frac{7\pi}{15}}
\\[0.2cm]
&\hspace*{1cm}\tikznode{1p}{\frac{1}{2}\sin\frac{2\pi}{15}}\\[0.3cm]
&\hspace*{1.5cm}\tikznode{2p}{\frac{1}{2^2}\sin\frac{4\pi}{15}}\\[0.3cm]
&\hspace*{2.5cm}\tikznode{3p}{\frac{1}{2^3}\sin\frac{8\pi}{15}=
\frac{1}{2^3}\sin\frac{7\pi}{15}}\\[0.3cm]
&\hspace*{3.5cm}\tikznode{4p}{\frac{1}{2^4}\sin\frac{14\pi}{15}=\frac{1}{2^4}\sin\frac{1\pi}{15}}\\[0.3cm]
\end{align*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
 \draw[dashed] ([yshift=-4pt]1.south west) -- ([yshift=-4pt]1.south east);
 \foreach \X in {2,3,4}
 {\draw ([yshift=2.5mm]\X p.north west) -- ++(0,-0.15cm) -| (\X.south);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thats smooth!!!